# hyperledger PHANTOM_READ_CONFLICT .vs. MVCC_READ_CONFLICT

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I used to get MVCC_READ_CONFLICT error and know what that means, but recently I upgrade it to enterprise version and starts getting PHANTOM_READ_CONFLICT error insted, what does PHANTOM_READ_CONFLICT mean?  Did try to google it but was not able to find anything about it.

Also how is it different from MVCC_READ_CONFLICT, I know how to handle MVCC_READ_CONFLICT but not PHANTOM_READ_CONFLICT  because I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 5):

Phantom reads are when you have a range query in your chaincode, and at time of commit - the range query is re-run and the result is different than the result that you had during the chaincode execution.

Imagine you do a range query and then count the number of elements and write the result to a key "count".
It may be that after the execution of the chaincode and before the commit - someone inserted a new element. Without a range query re-validation during commit time - the transaction would have written the wrong value of count.

From the [official documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/readwrite.html):

> This additional validation should ensure that no key has been
>   inserted/deleted/updated in the super range (i.e., union of the
>   ranges) of the results captured in the query-info(s). In other words,
>   if we re-execute any of the range queries (that the transaction
>   performed during simulation) during validation on the committed-state,
>   it should yield the same results that were observed by the transaction
>   at the time of simulation. This check ensures that if a transaction
>   observes phantom items during commit, the transaction should be marked
>   as invalid. Note that the this phantom protection is limited to range
>   queries (i.e., GetStateByRange function in the chaincode) and not yet
>   implemented for other queries (i.e., GetQueryResult function in the
>   chaincode). Other queries are at risk of phantoms, and should
>   therefore only be used in read-only transactions that are not
>   submitted to ordering, unless the application can guarantee the
>   stability of the result set between simulation and validation/commit
>   time.